# Return of doubleValue() method of java.lang.Number class

Tags: java

i need your help in following code snap.

```
public class Ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number number = new Float(1000000.211);
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(number.byteValue());
        System.out.println(number.shortValue());
        System.out.println(number.intValue());
        System.out.println(number.longValue());
        System.out.println(number.floatValue());
        System.out.println(number.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

output:

> 1000000.2
>
> 64
>
> 16960
>
> 1000000
>
> 1000000
>
> 1000000.2
>
> **1000000.1875**

**Question**: So I create instance of Float and store into Number class reference variable and also able to call methods of Number class. when I call **doubleValue()** method that time output value is changed after fraction.

I also read out implementation of **doubleValue()** method in Float class.

```
public double doubleValue() {
    return (double)value;
}
```

They just convert type cast the value into double then why output value is differ.

Please give your suggestions and views.

Comment: And you could ask why `1000000.211F` become `1000000.2F`